# How do I move an image left of right in activity window in Android

Tags: android

I'm new to Android programming and I'm wondering how do program my code so when i press button, it'll make the image on activity window move in the direction I want. My XML layout is relative layout with couple images on the activity window.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want an animation. Create a new XML-file (tween animation) in a new folder named `anim`, and call it something like `imageanimation.xml`. In the xml, try something like: `<translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-200"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:zAdjustment="top" />`

Where `android:duration` is how long you want the animation to last (in milliseconds), and `android:fromXDelta` and `android:toXDelta` is from where to where on the screen you want the image to move. `XDelta` is right and left, `YDelta` is up and down. In this example, it will start out from outside the screen and slide in from the left. Play a bit around with the values until you find what you are (hopefully) looking for.

Then, in the `onCreateListener` of your button, try something like `*yourImageView*.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.imageanimation));`

Good luck, and I hope this is something around what you are looking for. If not, please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Hello, after looking at several examples including yours I ended up trying translateanimation, here is what i got:  Animation posX = new TranslateAnimation(0, 20, 0, 0); //declare animation across x axis  btn_right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnright1);//button click to move image  btn_right.setOnClickListener(btnHandler);  //onclick listener.  I also set the following  img.startAnimation(posX);
    img.setVisibility(0);
    posX.setFillAfter(true);   problem is that when i click the same button again, the image reset back to where it was before, is there way to disable that?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you press the button the second time? Just nothing at all? If so, just make a boolean `boolean animPlayed;` and set that to true once the animation plays. Then, in your onclick, arrange an if-check to see if the animation is already been played: `if(!animationPlayed) img.playAnimation(posX);` 

If this is not what you meant, please elaborate a bit what you want to happen.

Comment: I want my image set to new location after I press the button, so when I press the button and it moves 20px to the left, I press the button again and it moves 20px  to the left.  I think I have do it in onAnimatonEnd under AnimationListener, but I don't know what to put in there.  TranlsateAnimation is probably not a good way to move an image though.  Thanks

Comment: If you want it to move 20px in the same direction each time, just declare the amount of px in your class, like ´int moveX = 0;´. Then, in your onClick, say ´moveX = moveX + 20;´ and then declare the animation as ´new TranslateAnimation(0, moveX, 0, 0); before you say ´img.startAnimation(*yourAnimation*);´. All of this inside your onClick. Is that kind of what you want?